# How change in the login md5 to pwdcompare

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I just switched to mssql 2008 and there have changed the old md5 password line coding with pwdcompare 
My question is how to change this and get login into db ?

```
$check['account']['ID'] == $data['accountName'] and 
$check['account']['Password'] == md5($data['password']))
```

My database is look like this.

```
[ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Password] [varbinary](50) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: just switched to mssql 2008... so which db you using earlier?

Comment: The old was mssql 2005 and used password encript .md5 Now i got the newer version of my server and this use now pwdcompare .. I want use the old php with changed login method :/